# phpmyadmin - list files in directory

Tags: apache, list, phpmyadmin

I have apache+mysql+phpmyadmnin under Gentoo.

> phpmyadmin-3.2.2

It worked fine before, but now, when I'm loading **http://localhost/phpmyadmin** I get a list of flies in phpmyadmin-directory, and when I chose index.php, I get it's own code.

What I did wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It means that apache does not recognizes neither of your files as php executables.  Maybe you run an 'emerge update world' and then an 'env-update' which install a new apache2 version and then re-write the old apache config file.  As LiraNuna mentioned, you need to check that the phpMyAdmin directory contains the proper instruction to load the proper PHP module.  In this way apache will know how to handle the php files.

This is what I have on /etc/apache2/vhosts.d/default_vhost.include under the phpMyAdmin Directory definition:

```
Alias /phpMyAdmin /var/www/localhost/htdocs/phpMyAdmin
   <Directory /var/www/localhost/htdocs/phpMyAdmin>
   Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
   DirectoryIndex index.php
   # Authorize for setup
   <Files setup.php>
   # For Apache 1.3 and 2.0
         <IfModule mod_auth.c>
             AuthType Basic
             AuthName "phpMyAdmin Setup"
             AuthUserFile /etc/phpmyadmin/htpasswd.setup
         </IfModule>
   # For Apache 2.2
         <IfModule mod_authn_file.c>
             AuthType Basic
             AuthName "phpMyAdmin Setup"
             AuthUserFile /etc/phpmyadmin/htpasswd.setup
         </IfModule>
         Require valid-user
   </Files>
   <IfModule mod_php4.c>
         AddType application/x-httpd-php .php
         php_flag magic_quotes_gpc Off
         php_flag track_vars On
         php_flag register_globals Off
         php_value include_path .
   </IfModule>
   <IfModule mod_php5.c>
         AddType application/x-httpd-php .php
         php_flag magic_quotes_gpc Off
         php_flag track_vars On
         php_flag register_globals Off
         php_value include_path .
   </IfModule>
</Directory>
```

This should solve your problem.

Comment: Could you post all content of that file? Here is mine: http://dpaste.com/102960/ .There aren't any parts connected with phpmyadmin.

Comment: I posted the relevant part.  I think your apache configuration probably was wiped out by an 'env-update'.

Answer (score 0):

Is `mod_php5` installed? If so, do you have the php handler set up to handle `.php` files?

```
<IfModule mod_php5.c>
  AddType application/x-httpd-php .php .phtml .php4 .php3
  AddType application/x-httpd-php-source .phps
</IfModule>
```

If you are not using `mod_php5`, do you use any form of CGI? Do the `.php` files have execute permissions?

Comment: I don't use mod_php5 and don't use CGI.

Comment: all files from /var/www/localhost/htdocs/phpmyadmin has admin as owner O_o

Comment: "I don't use mod_php5 and don't use CGI." -- Then how do you expect to run **php**MyAdmin?